# Word Interop Not Working In A Scheduled Task

Tags: ms-word, interop, ms-office, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I'm currently developing a script that takes a Word document, opens it up in Word, and then prints the Word file as a PDF. Everything works great when run manually either on my machine or the server. The problem comes in when I attempt to run it as a scheduled task.

One of the requirements is that this should be done nightly without any intervention. When I set up a schedule task to do this and set the security options to "Run only when user is logged on" everything works fine. Problem is, this has to be run with or without someone being logged on. If I set the task to "Run whether user is logged on or not", the script fails on the following line:

```
wordDoc = MSWord.Documents.Open(ref fileToConvert, ref refFalse, ref refTrue, 
                                ref RN, ref RN, ref RN, ref RN, ref RN,
                                ref RN, ref RN, ref RN, ref RN, ref RN,
                                ref RN, ref RN, ref RN);
```

`MSWord.Documents.Open()` works, but returns null.

This task is running on Windows Server 2008 with Office 2007.

Is there another approach I should be taking for this?

Comment: I had the exact same problem, spent ages trying to resolve it, went down various dead ends, and eventually the "solution" I ended up with was: not to use Windows Server 2008. If you find a solution to this, I'll be all ears.

Comment: So does it work if you're not using Server 2008?

Comment: On Windows 2003 server or on XP, yes. Not sure about Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that many people have tried to do something close to what you are attempting and failed. There is a lot of chatter about not being able to run any office interop based solutions in a server-like mode (unattended etc).

See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=257757) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/8820544d-754c-400e-8ffd-53b8d66bb8ee)

I know this is probably not the answer you were looking for but it is nevertheless how it is!

Comment: I was looking for any answer. I couldn't find any information regarding what was happening from a bunch of Google searches so thank you for your input. I'm going to give it a few more hours and if a "solution" isn't posted, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 27):

I've had problems automating Office from a Windows Service under Windows Server 2008, even though that works fine under Windows Server 2003. The problem also occurs at the Open call, though it actually raises an exception rather than simply returning null. Anyway, you might want to try this...

I tried following the advice given by H Ogawa in [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91), and it seemed to work. It's bizarre, but kudos to Mr. Ogawa for discovering it.

Summary of the 'Ogawa Hack': create a desktop folder for the system profile, as either

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`, or

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

...depending on whether you have 64-bit Windows.

Also, the folder needs write permission for whatever user is "driving" Office.

[Edit: corrected link URL]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have to take a look as soon as time allows. I'll post back if it works or not.

Comment: Works wonderfully! This saved me tons of (additional) headache with this...now let's hope nothing actually breaks from running Word from a service.

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to add the user to the Local Admin group and check the "Run with highest privileges" option.

Comment: Great hack, didn't even know how that was identified. Worked like a magic :)

Comment: Yeah It worked for me too.. I was struggling for the past 5 hours and creating that folder did the trick...

Comment: I was really hopeful that this would work for me. It did nothing on Win Server 2012 or 2016.

Comment: This worked for me with Win Server 2012 R2 64bit with an automated process running the Word .Open(...). Account is also allowed to login as batch and service under Win security policies.

Comment: Thank for solution, still working in 2023 with combination of Word with "Run whether user is logged on or not"